# Exibir/Esconder “uma div” ao clicar em radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como faço para que, ao marcar um radio buttom, ele libere um conteúdo de uma div?
Tipo este exemplo so que usando radio buttom! Obrigado

```
    <label>Mostrar termos:</label> <input type="checkbox" id="termos" />
<div id="termoTexto">
    Seus termos estarão aqui
</div>


    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #termoTexto{
    display: block;
}
#termoTexto {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar o `id` do radio como seletor. Mas o radio tem comportamento diferente do checkbox, que pode ser marcado/desmarcado.

```css
#termos:checked ~ #termoTexto{
    display: block;
}
#termoTexto {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<label>Mostrar termos:</label> <input type="radio" id="termos" />
<div id="termoTexto">
    Seus termos estarão aqui
</div>
```

---

Já que colocou a tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) na pergunta, tem uma solução com JavaScript também:

```js
document.getElementById("termos").onclick = function(){
   document.getElementById("termoTexto").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#termoTexto {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<label>Mostrar termos:</label> <input type="radio" id="termos" />
<div id="termoTexto">
    Seus termos estarão aqui
</div>
```

Basta alterar o `display` do elemento ao clicar no radio.

Comment: <div class="panel-body " id="formadepagamento">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-left h3">
                        Forma de Pagamento
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                
            </div>

Comment: ele não exibi esta div

Comment: A resposta é baseada no que está na pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei uma forma usando JS.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo