# Tenho um campo no qual ao ativar checkebox, ele desabilita o input

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um campo no qual ao ativar o `checkebox`, ele desabilita o `input`, mas quando recarrego a página o `checkebox` fica desativado, assim tendo que ativá-lo novamente.

```js
function desabilitar(selecionado) {
    document.getElementById('tel').disabled = selecionado;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="NomeEscola" style="font-weight: normal">Telefone Residencial:
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="desabilitar(this.checked)"/> O mesmo do aluno</label>
  <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TelefoneResidencial" id="tel" data-inputmask="'alias': '(99)9999-9999'" maxlength="150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer que ao carregar a página o checkbox já venha marcado e o campo desabilitado?

Comment: Assim, se eu marca ele, dai recarrego a pagina então deve permanecer marcada, o mesmo ao contrario

Comment: Vai conseguir fazer isso utilizando **localStorage**:  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage

Comment: e faltou completar a sua pergunta?

Comment: Outra coisa, ele desativa 1 imput, como faria para quando marca a checkbox, desativasse mais de um?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar um `localStorage` para salvar o valor do parâmetro `selecionado`. Depois você verifica se ele existe e é igual a "true" e dispara um click no checkbox. Mas coloque um `id` no checkbox para saber exatamente onde será disparado o click:

```
<input id="mesmoaluno" type="checkbox" onclick="desabilitar(this.checked)"/>
       ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

**Código:**

```
function desabilitar(selecionado) {
   document.getElementById('tel').disabled = selecionado;
   localStorage.setItem("checked", selecionado); // cria o localStorage
}

// aguarda o DOM ser carregado
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // verifica se o localStorage existe e é igual a "true"
   if(localStorage.getItem("checked") === "true"){
      document.getElementById("mesmoaluno").click(); // dispara o click no checkbox
   }
});
```

> Não coloquei um snippet funcional aqui porque ele não aceita
>   `localStorage`, mas neste [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/k53u8d62/) é possível testar. Basta marcar/desmarcar o checkbox e clicar em "RUN" novamente.

Comment: E Outra coisa, ele desativa 1 imput, como faria para quando marca a checkbox, desativasse mais de um?

Comment: Basta vc colocar dentro da função os inputs que quer desabilitar, assim como fez com o `document.getElementById('tel').disabled = selecionado;`.

Comment: Não deixe de marcar uma resposta das suas perguntas com ✔️ (apenas uma resposta).

Comment: desculpa como marco a pergunta?

Comment: Veja tb [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/436271/8063) que vc não marcou =]